# How do I create a template to read mongo connection details for apache beam cloud dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a dataflow template that can get connection strings details , database and collection details at run time for gcp dataflow job but this is not working with below code.

```
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        # Use add_value_provider_argument for arguments to be templatable
        # Use add_argument as usual for non-templatable arguments
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--input',
            required=False,
            help='Path of the file to read from')

        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--mongo',
            required=False,
            help='Mongo Connection String')

        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--database',
            required=False,
            help='database')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--collection',
            required=False,
            help='collection')

        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--batch_size',
            required=False,
            help='batch_size')

def run(argv=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=user_options) as p:
        files = p | 'ReadFromGCS' >> ReadFromTextWithFilename(user_options.input)

        # Count the occurrences of each word.
        def parse_json(element):
            file_path, meta = element
            name = file_path.split('/')[-1]
            try:
                paper = json.loads(meta)
                paper['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.now()
                return paper
            except ValueError as e:
                return {
                    'failed': "true",
                    'file_name': name,
                    "file_path": file_path,
                    'reason': 'JSON parsing error: {}'.format(e),
                    'timestamp':datetime.datetime.now()

                }

        records = files | 'Parse' >> beam.Map(parse_json)

        records | 'write to mongo' >> beam.io.WriteToMongoDB(
            uri=user_options.mongo.get(),
            db=user_options.database.get(),
            coll=user_options.collection.get(),
            batch_size=int(user_options.batch_size.get()))
```

but I am facing this issue

apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: batch_size, type: str, default_value: None).get() not called from a runtime context

How do I solve this?

I tried to create value provider as mentioned in documentation of Cloud dataflow
but that does not seem to be working.Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

When using ValueProviders, you cannot use `.get()` during the pipeline/DAG creation.

You can only use during the execution of your Beam code (e.g., transforms, DoFn, etc). During the pipeline creation, those values should not be known, as you want them to be passed dynamically.

Doing `.get()` at the time of the creation wouldn't allow you to change it when creating a job with the template.

Please check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#about-runtime-parameters-and-the-valueprovider-interface for more information.

---

That said, unfortunately here, not all IOs accept ValueProviders. To have a complete support of IOs and avoid the use of ValueProviders, it is recommended to use [Flex Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates).

With Flex Templates, your pipeline creation code is ran directly on Dataflow before the job is executed, so it can give you a lot of flexibility not supported on [Classic Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates).